# Form for one model with many objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

UPD.
I need to display multiple records of a single model in a form.Then after updating some values I need to save all the records data at once..that is my form view should work like a spread sheet.
The requirement is, from one table I need to get data and populate all rows in a form. After that I have to edit some columns then and I should save all records of this model to database at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually) which presents how to edit multiple records in one form.

Comment: ty, but this not what im looking for, check updated question please.